# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object REACT DASHBOARD

Tags: javascript, react-hooks

les traigo un problema que estoy teniendo a ver si alguien podría ayudarme, no le encuentro la vuelta. En react necesito mostrar las categorias de mi sitio, junto con la cantidad de productos que tiene cada categoria.
**Esta es la función que estoy planteando:**

```
import React from 'react';

import '../assets/css/tables.css'

import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';



function PanelCategorias(){

    const [categories, setCategories] = useState([0]);
    console.log(useState([0]));

    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log('Se visualizan los datos');
        fetch('/api/categories')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            setCategories(data.data)
        })
        .catch(error => console.error(error));
    },[])

    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log('Se actualizaron los datos');
    },[categories])

    useEffect(()=>{
        return()=> console.log('Se dejaron de visualizar los datos')
    },[categories])

    let todas = Object.keys(categories)
    console.log(todas)

    let cant = Object.values(categories)
    console.log(cant)

    return(

    <div className='table'>
        <h2>Listado de Categorías</h2>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Categorías</th>
                    <th>Cantidad</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            {todas.map((cat , i)=>{
                return(
                    <tr key={i}>
                <td >
                        {cat}
                </td> 
                <td >
                        {cant[i]}
                </td> 
                </tr>)
                })}   
            
        </table>
    </div>

    )
}
```

export default PanelCategorias

**Por otro lado, esta es la información que le estoy compartiendo a la API a traves del link fetch:**

```
{
"total": 4,
"data": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "category_description": "Mujer",
        "products": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Calza negra Reebok",
                "description": "calza deportiva",
                "price": "10000.00",
                "discount": null,
                "category_id": 1,
                "carroCompras_id": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Calza estampada Reebok",
                "description": "calza deportiva",
                "price": "100.00",
                "discount": 10,
                "category_id": 1,
                "carroCompras_id": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Remera River Plate",
                "description": "Remera de river femenina",
                "price": "10000.00",
                "discount": 10,
                "category_id": 1,
                "carroCompras_id": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "category_description": "Hombre",
        "products": [
            {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "Remera River Plate",
                "description": "Remera de river hombre",
                "price": "25000.00",
                "discount": null,
                "category_id": 2,
                "carroCompras_id": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "name": "Short River Plate",
                "description": "Pantalos de futbol de river hombre",
                "price": "7999.00",
                "discount": null,
                "category_id": 2,
                "carroCompras_id": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "category_description": "Zapatillas",
        "products": [
            {
                "id": 6,
                "name": "Zapatillas Adidas Urbanas",
                "description": "Zapatillas urbanas",
                "price": "24999.99",
                "discount": null,
                "category_id": 3,
                "carroCompras_id": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 7,
                "name": "Zapatillas Adidas Running",
                "description": "Zapatillas de running",
                "price": "24999.99",
                "discount": null,
                "category_id": 3,
                "carroCompras_id": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "category_description": "Accesorios",
        "products": [
            {
                "id": 8,
                "name": "Reloj Smart sports",
                "description": "Reloj inteligente para running",
                "price": "35900.99",
                "discount": null,
                "category_id": 4,
                "carroCompras_id": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 9,
                "name": "Vinchas termicas Running",
                "description": "Vinchas termicas para Running",
                "price": "4000.00",
                "discount": null,
                "category_id": 4,
                "carroCompras_id": 1
            }
        ]
    }
],
"status": 200
```

}

**Parte del Error que se visualiza en consola:**
"*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object at Function.keys () at PanelCategorias (PanelCategorias.jsx:32:1)*"

Desde ya, gracias a cualquier ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

el problema que indicas en tu pregunta se centra en tu componente PanelCategorias al declarar las variables "todas" y "cant" utilizando la variable de estado "categories", para resolver esto te aconsejo declarar estas variables utilizando igualmente el hook useState, y en tu hook useEffect el cual tienes declarado para cuando se actualiza la variable de estado "categories" puedes actualizarlas de la siguiente manera.

```
const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);
const [todas, setTodas] = useState([])
const [cant, setCant] = useState([])

useEffect(()=>{
    console.log('Se actualizaron los datos');

    //Actualizar todas y cant en base a los datos de categories una vez que este se actualiza
    setTodas(Object.keys(categories))
    setCant(Object.values(categories))
},[categories])
```

De esta manera los datos de "todas" y "cant" se actualizaran en base a los datos de "categories" cada vez que este ultimo se actualice.

Ahora, **tendrás otro problema cuando resuelvas esto** ya que por lo que entiendo deseas mostrar el nombre de cada categoria con la cantidad de productos que contiene, lo cual no obtendrás con la función Object.keys() ni tampoco Object.values(), te dejo a continuacion un pequeño codigo el cual te imprime lo que obtienes utilizando estas funciones con los datos que indicas en tu pregunta.

```js
const datos_json = {
  "total": 4,
  "data": [{
      "id": 1,
      "category_description": "Mujer",
      "products": [{
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Calza negra Reebok",
          "description": "calza deportiva",
          "price": "10000.00",
          "discount": null,
          "category_id": 1,
          "carroCompras_id": 1
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Calza estampada Reebok",
          "description": "calza deportiva",
          "price": "100.00",
          "discount": 10,
          "category_id": 1,
          "carroCompras_id": 1
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "Remera River Plate",
          "description": "Remera de river femenina",
          "price": "10000.00",
          "discount": 10,
          "category_id": 1,
          "carroCompras_id": 1
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "category_description": "Hombre",
      "products": [{
          "id": 4,
          "name": "Remera River Plate",
          "description": "Remera de river hombre",
          "price": "25000.00",
          "discount": null,
          "category_id": 2,
          "carroCompras_id": 1
        },
        {
          "id": 5,
          "name": "Short River Plate",
          "description": "Pantalos de futbol de river hombre",
          "price": "7999.00",
          "discount": null,
          "category_id": 2,
          "carroCompras_id": 1
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "category_description": "Zapatillas",
      "products": [{
          "id": 6,
          "name": "Zapatillas Adidas Urbanas",
          "description": "Zapatillas urbanas",
          "price": "24999.99",
          "discount": null,
          "category_id": 3,
          "carroCompras_id": 1
        },
        {
          "id": 7,
          "name": "Zapatillas Adidas Running",
          "description": "Zapatillas de running",
          "price": "24999.99",
          "discount": null,
          "category_id": 3,
          "carroCompras_id": 1
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "category_description": "Accesorios",
      "products": [{
          "id": 8,
          "name": "Reloj Smart sports",
          "description": "Reloj inteligente para running",
          "price": "35900.99",
          "discount": null,
          "category_id": 4,
          "carroCompras_id": 1
        },
        {
          "id": 9,
          "name": "Vinchas termicas Running",
          "description": "Vinchas termicas para Running",
          "price": "4000.00",
          "discount": null,
          "category_id": 4,
          "carroCompras_id": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "status": 200
}

const todas = Object.keys(datos_json.data)
const cant = Object.values(datos_json.data)
console.log(todas)
console.log(cant)
```

Como puedes ver la funcion Object.keys() y Object.values() no estan obteniendo los datos que deseas utilizar y mostrar en pantalla, para recuperar estos datos puedes hacerlo directamente ejecutando la función .map con la variable de estado "categories" de la siguiente manera:

```
import React from 'react';
import '../assets/css/tables.css'

import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function PanelCategorias(){

const [categories, setCategories] = useState([0]);

useEffect(()=>{
    console.log('Se visualizan los datos');
    fetch('/api/categories')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        setCategories(data.data)
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
},[])

useEffect(()=>{
    console.log('Se actualizaron los datos');
},[categories])

useEffect(()=>{
    return()=> console.log('Se dejaron de visualizar los datos')
},[categories])


return(

    <div className='table'>
        <h2>Listado de Categorías</h2>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Categorías</th>
                    <th>Cantidad</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            {categories.map((category , i)=>{
                return(
                    <tr key={i}>
                <td >
                        {category.category_description}
                </td> 
                <td >
                        {category.category_description.products.length}
                </td> 
                </tr>)
                })}   
            
        </table>
    </div>

)
}

export default PanelCategorias
```

De esta manera puedes imprimir las datos que deseas utilizando directamente la variable de estado "categories"

Saludos, te adjunto enlaces con lectura recomendada para entender mejor lo dicho en esta respuesta.

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values

https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html